# AnguarJS with ES2016 load config module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to start a new Angular 1 Application based on ES6. I use webpack and the babel-loader to convert the JS.

My problem now is to load an own config module. Please have a look at this:

```
// config/config.js
import angular from 'angular';

export default angular.module('config')
    .factory('config', () => {
        return {
            url: {
                products: 'https://....'
            },
            products: []
        }
    })
```

The corresponding app.js reads (I stripped some imports):

```
import angular  from 'angular';

import config from './config/config';
import HomeCtrl from './controller/HomeController';


let app = () => {
  return {
    template: require('./app.html')
  }
};


const MODULE_NAME = 'app';

angular.module(MODULE_NAME, [uiRouter, config])
    .directive('myapp', app)
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'config', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, config) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            "url": "/",
            "template": require('./views/home.html'),
            "controller": HomeCtrl,
            'controllerAs': 'app'
        })


    }]);


export default MODULE_NAME;
```

The error message says:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'config' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

What did I missed here? Is there a better way to load an application wide config object to use in certain services?

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you're starting from scratch, skip Angular1 and use Angular2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a module, you have to call `module()` with two args: the name and the dependencies. If you call it with only one parameter, you get the existing module with that name.

Change your module `config` declaration to:

```
export default angular.module('config', [])
    .factory('config', () => {
        return {
            url: {
                products: 'https://....'
            },
            products: []
        }
    }).name
```

In addition, I always export only the `.name` of a new module. When you import the module, you just need its name.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the best solution. The second argument in my definition was missing indeed. And exporting the `.name` only solves the problem, that you have to define a string as dependency configuration as mentioned by @ovidiu-dolha and @VadimB . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your dependent modules in your main module definition you need to use the string identifier, not the actual angular.module (at least here it's specified as Array[String]: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

So, you should change to this:

```
angular.module(MODULE_NAME, ['config'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check Angular documentation - module dependencies it's array of strings, but not dependent modules types or instances

`angular.module(name, [requires], [configFn]);`

when

`requires (optional) Array<string>`

So your solution to use next declaration
`angular.module(MODULE_NAME, ['config'])`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module